# How to prevent sign up with existing username?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, authentication

I'm trying to create a forum application using Python. My log-in function:

```
uname = username_const.get()
pword = password_const.get()

# this will delete the entry after login button is pressed
username.delete(0, END)
password.delete(0, END)

conn = sqlite3.connect('users_info.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT username, password FROM users")
account_list = c.fetchall()
flag = True
for account in account_list:
    if uname == account[0] and pword == account[1]:
        raise_frame(exsisting_account_frame)  # allow the user to log into his account
        flag = False
    elif uname == account[0]:
        password_not_recognised() #presents an error message
        flag = False
if flag:
    user_not_found() #presents an error message
```

My sign-up function (doesn't allow already existing/taken username):

```
new_uname = newUsername_const.get()

conn = sqlite3.connect('users_info.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT username FROM users")
usernames = c.fetchall()

for user_name in usernames:
    if user_name == new_uname:
        username_already_exists()
        flag = False
        break
    else:
        flag = True

if flag:
    new_fname = name_const.get()
    new_mail = mail_const.get()
    new_uname = newUsername_const.get()
    new_pword = newPassword_const.get()

    FullName.delete(0, END)
    mailAccount.delete(0, END)
    newUsername.delete(0, END)
    newPassword.delete(0, END)

    conn = sqlite3.connect('users_info.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO users (fullname, mail, username, password) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",
              (new_fname, new_mail, new_uname, new_pword))
    raise_frame(new_account_frame)
    conn.commit()
```

The login functionality works but the sign-up functionality still allows a taken username. How can I fix it?

Comment: Define the username as `unique` in your table schema.

Comment: Would that prevent users to use a taken username ? It won't allow to use this value? @tonypdmtr

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you should do is that the username field in the table is indexed without duplicates, with that restriction you should not let it save the new record.

Comment: Thanks, how can i do that? @EduardoAlonso

Answer (score 0):

> "... *how can I fix it??*"

Define `UNIQUE` constraint on `username` column:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    regdate     TEXT            NOT NULL    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    fullname    TEXT,
    mail        TEXT    UNIQUE  NOT NULL,
    username    TEXT    UNIQUE  NOT NULL,
    password    TEXT            NOT NULL
);
```

SQLite returns constraint-violation error for `INSERT` statements containing already existing usernames (and/or email addresses) now (data integrity should be enforced by database, not application). [More info](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) (click *table-constraint*). Skipping `id` and `regdate` columns on `INSERT` statements assigns them default values.

> "... *sign-up functionality still allow to sign up to the app using a taken account that's saved in the database...*"

Query for existing username like:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username = 'already_taken_username_here';
```

Returns single record, single field, containing either `0` or `1` (no need for `for` -loop, nor `flag` variable).

Consider storing `password` as a hash (instead of plain-text). Hash password input (on login) prior to comparing to database record.

Comment: thank! @user4157124 if I add 'id' and 'regdate' to my CREATE variables, to i have to insert spesific values to them too in the INSERT command? if so, what values?

Comment: could you also explain what the "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username = 'already_taken_username_here';" does? how am I supposed to use this command?

Comment: Write `INSERT` query as if `id` and `regdate` don't exist. "*Skipping `id` and `regdate` columns on `INSERT` statements assigns them default values.*" `count()` counts records which conform to `WHERE` clause (either `0` if `username` doesn't exist, `1` if it does). Replace `'already_taken_username_here'` by `new_uname` variable's value. Use `SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = 'login_name_here';` (on login) so `for account in account_list:` -loop isn't needed (returns single record, single field, being either `NULL` if login name isn't registered, or its password if it is).